# How to install a Varnish module on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, varnish

I want to install an additional module for Varnish Cache, the [Shield module](https://github.com/varnish/libvmod-shield).

How can I do that? I installed Varnish 3.0 from the Ubuntu repositories.

How do I get the Varnish source which the module needs to compile? Do I need to compile Varnish from source as well? Does this disable updating Varnish through the repositories?

Can someone give a step-by-step instruction?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the source packages with

```
apt-get source varnish
```

It looks like the module only requires the varnish sources for the header files so you don't need to compile varnish. You should be ok to continue updating varnish from the reops although when you upgrade the main package be prepared to download the source and rebuild the module.

If you downloaded the module source to your $HOME/libvmod-shield and the varnish is in $HOME/varnish-3.0.2 then

```
cd $HOME/libvmod-shield
./configure VARNISHSRC=$HOME/varnish-3.0.2
make 
sudo make install
sudo make check
```

or something similar should get you going.

Comment: I had to build the Varnish source first, then I had to also specify the module directory like `./configure VARNISHSRC=/usr/local/src/varnish-3.0.0 VMODDIR=/usr/lib/varnish/vmods`

Comment: @Tobe : I'm facing a similar problem. Could you please tell me how I can build safely. I fear that building would mess with the varnish, as it is already installed. Thanks

Comment: Take a backup of your configuration-files, then you can restore Varnish from the repositories if something goes wrong. But it should be pretty safe to install. Try following Ians suggestion, other than that I can't help you.

Answer (score 3):

I know you asked about how to do this on Ubuntu, but this answer comes up in searches. :)

On CentOS (or other RHEL-based systems), you want to do something like this:

```
rpm -i "http://example.com/varnish.src.rpm"
rpmbuild -bc /usr/src/redhat/SPECS/varnish.spec

cd libvmod-foo
./configure VARNISHSRC=/usr/src/redhat/BUILD/varnish-$VERSION
make
make install
```